# Randomly change to 1 p element of a zero list in python

Tags: python

I have a zero list with size of `m`. I wanna randomly select `p` indexes and change them to 1.

`Y = [0 for x in range(M)]`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @OmarEinea I have a zero list. I want to randomly change `p` of them to 1. (p<m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

m, p = 5, 2
l = [0] * m

indices = list(range(len(l)))
random.shuffle(indices)

for i in indices[:p]:
    l[i] = 1
```

As mentioned by @MrT in the comments if you don't already have your "zero list" you can do:

```
l = [0] * (m - p) + [1] * p
random.shuffle(l)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `a = [0] * (m - p) + [1] * p, random.shuffle(a)` be faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use random.sample()

```
import random

m,p = 10, 5
my_list = [0]*m
index = random.sample(range(len(my_list)), p)

for i in index:
    my_list[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

x = [1 if bool(random.getrandbits(1)) else 0 for i in x]

print(x) # [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-

```
import random

leninp = int(input("len"))

raninp = int(input("random"))

x = [0 for i in range(leninp-raninp)] + [1 for i in range(raninp)]

random.shuffle(x)

print(x)
```

Comment: I have a zero list. I want to randomly change p of them to 1. (p<m). p and m are input.